# Regular Polygons - Why sum of internal angles always divisible by 3, 6, and 9

Tags: geometry

I admit, I have never been good with numbers. However, I have a project which requires understanding basic geometry of regular polygons.

During my analysis of regular polygons with equilateral sides from n=3 to 150, I was searching for those polygons whose interior sum of angles was perfectly divisible by 3, 6, or 9.

My best Excel skills seem to reveal that ANY/ALL regular polygons have a sum of internal angles that is perfectly divisible by 3, 6, AND 9.

Can that be correct?

I am completely amazed and confused. Could someone take the time to explain why this occurs? or educate me as to what I might be doing wrong?

My math is very simple. I take the sum of the internal angles (n-2)*180 and divide by 3, 6, and 9. In my spreadsheet, I display the remainder of the division calculation. It always displays as 0.000
I am positive that I am doing this correctly because the columns where I divide by 7 and 11 actually show the correct remainders of the operations.

The formula in Excel is =MOD(X,y) where the output should be the remainder.

One example, The sum of the interior angles of a regular dodecahedron is (12-2)*180=1800 which is divisible by 3,6, and 9.
The more I manually check, the more I become convinced that EVERY sum of internal angles is divisible by 3,6,9 but not 7 and 11.

But, I cannot figure out why.
Please shed some light on this phenomenon.

Comment: 180 is divisible by 3, 6, 9, and the sum of the interior angles is an integer multiple of 180. So, in fact, "every sum of interior angles is divisible by 180".

Comment: The polygons don't even have to be regular. They just have to be non-self-intersecting (an hourglass-shaped quadrilateral, for instance, is not allowed).

Comment: You can divide it to $n-2$ triangle which is $180(n-2)$ which always divide by 3, 6 and 9.

Comment: @halrankard TY! So... If I understand correctly, we are actually 'injecting' this property of divisibility by 3,6,and 9 (as well as 2,4) by the mere fact that (n-2) is multiplied by 180 
which is itself divisible by 2,3,4,6, and 9. After thinking about it all day and all night, it makes sense. Wish I had found math this interesting as a younger man.